# Pass model and extra parameter from view to an action in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, model

I am trying to pass a `userid` to my action in controller .my action is like this as you can see here:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Expert")]
        public ActionResult AddExpert(AssistanceJuror assistanceJuror,int UserId)
        {
            User user = objUserRepository.FindBy(i => i.Id == assistanceJuror.UserId).First();
            user.Enable = "فعال";
            assistanceJuror.Date = DateTime.Now;
            objUserRepository.Edit(user);
            objUserRepository.Save();
            objAssistanceJurorRepository.Add(assistanceJuror);
            TempData["Message"] = "کارشناس به معاونت اختصاص داده شد";
            objAssistanceJurorRepository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("IndexExpert", "Assistance");
        }
```

So this action expect 2 parameters ,one of that is my model and another one is `userId` .so i need to get both values from the view my view is like this :

```
@using ViewModelDomain
@using Repository;
@model DomainClass.AssistanceJuror

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddExpert";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="wrapper-left">
        <div class="wrapper-top-addCompany">
            انتساب کارشناس به معاونت
            <div style="float: left; padding-left: 20px;">
                <div class="divider"></div>
                <div class="buttonPossion">
                    @Html.ActionLink("بازگشت", "Index", "Assistance", new { companyid = ViewBag.firstIdeaId }, new { @class = "buttonBlueLink" })
                </div>
                <div class="divider"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper-Member" style="padding-bottom: 30px; margin-bottom: 5px; width: 100%; min-height: 550px;">
            <h2>اضافه کردن کارشناس جدید
            </h2>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="editor-label">
                انتخاب معاونت
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AssistanceId, (SelectList)ViewBag.listAssistance)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                انتخاب کارشناس
            </div>
            @*                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.userId, (SelectList)ViewBag.listDisableExpert)
                </div>*@
            @{
    if (User.IsInRole("Expert") || User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
                <div class="wrapper-Member" style="border-top: 1px solid #d3d3d3; margin-top: 30px; width: 99.5%; border-left: 1px solid #d3d3d3; margin-right: 1px">
                    <div class="tab-list-company" style="margin-right: -1px; width: 180px">
                        <h2 style="font: normal 13px BHoma; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 2px;">اختصاص کارشناس به معاونت
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list-company" style="border: none; width: 98%">
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>نام و نام خانوادگی</th>
                                    <th>سطح تحصیلات</th>
                                    <th>رشته تحصیلی</th>
                                    <th>شماره همراه</th>
                                    <th>تلفن</th>
                                    <th>ایمیل</th>
                                    @if (User.IsInRole("Expert") || User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                                    {
                                        <th style="width: 20px;">اضافه</th>
                                    }
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            @{
                                    userRepository objUserRepository = new userRepository();
                                    //var listJuror = objUserRepository.FindBy(i => i.Permission == "Juror").ToList();
                                List<DomainClass.User> listDisableAssistance = objUserRepository.ReturnUserByEnablePermission("غیرفعال", "Assistance");
                            }

                            @foreach (var temp in listDisableAssistance)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @{
                                string fullName = temp.Name + " " + temp.Family;
                                        }
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => fullName)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => temp.EducationLevel)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => temp.Field)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => temp.Mobile)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => temp.Tell)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => temp.Email)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>


                                            @using (Html.BeginForm("AddExpert", "Assistance", routeValues: new { userid = temp.Id }))
                                       {
                                        <input type="submit" value=""  class="Add" title="اضافه کردن" />
                                       }    
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }

                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
    }
            }
        </div>
    </div>

}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

In this part

```
   <td>


                                                @using (Html.BeginForm("AddExpert", "Assistance", routeValues: new { userid = temp.Id }))
                                           {
                                            <input type="submit" value=""  class="Add" title="اضافه کردن" />
                                           }    
                                        </td>
```

I am trying to pass my `userId` to my action but it doesn't work and i get an error that says the userid is null .

Best regards

Comment: Your generating nested forms. Not sure if its the problem, but its invalid html and not supported in the standards so you should consider changing it. If the model is not null then I assume it must be bubbling up to the outer form and submitting that so the inner form route value may be ignored.

Comment: does your call arrive with the action with userid null?

Comment: @faby in first time that i click on submit i got this error :The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'userid'of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AddExpert(DomainClass.AssistanceJuror, Int32)' in 'Presentation.Controllers.AssistanceController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: @EA try to change the type of UserId from `int` to `int?` just to check if it is working or not..

Comment: @EA put a breakpoint in the first line of your action method. Does the call arrive there?

Comment: @EA does your temp.Id has a value?

Comment: @EA why are you passing only UserId parameter to the Controller? what about assistanceJuror parameter?

Comment: I don't know .I thought this submit button sends the model .am i right ?

Comment: I'm not sure, i think that you should send it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60241/discussion-between-faby-and-e-a).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that you are not sending the `assistanceJuror` parameter to the controller.

```
new { userid = temp.Id }
```

should be

```
new {assistanceJuror= value, userid = temp.Id }
```

but I think that `AssistanceJuror`  is a complex type so you'll get an error. Try sending only one id (for example) and get information from database in your controller.

Something like this

```
public ActionResult AddExpert(string assistanceJurorId,int UserId)
        {
            var assistanceJuror= //get Your Variable Here;
            User user = objUserRepository.FindBy(i => i.Id == assistanceJuror.UserId).First();
            user.Enable = "فعال";
            assistanceJuror.Date = DateTime.Now;
            objUserRepository.Edit(user);
            objUserRepository.Save();
            objAssistanceJurorRepository.Add(assistanceJuror);
            TempData["Message"] = "کارشناس به معاونت اختصاص داده شد";
            objAssistanceJurorRepository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("IndexExpert", "Assistance");
        }
```

and call it in this way from the view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddExpert", "Assistance", routeValues: new {assistanceJurorId= model.AssistanceId, userid = temp.Id }))
```

In this way you are not passing the selected value of the drop down list (that is stored in `model.AssistanceId` variable) to the controller

```
assistanceJurorId= model.AssistanceId
```

but  the initial value of the property in the model because the drop down list is made in this way

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AssistanceId, (SelectList)ViewBag.listAssistance))
```

To send the correct value of the selected element in the drop down list I suggest you to remove the Html. BeginForm and put an ajax call to your controller only on the submit of the form. In this way you are sure that the correct value will be send.

Comment: So what about assitanceId?How can i pass it to the controller?

Comment: @faby, _"In this way you are passing the selected value of the drop down list"_. No your not. Razor code is parsed on the server so the route that created in the `BeginForm()` method is based on the initial value of `AssistanceId`, not on the value that is selected by the user in the browser.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes you're right I have to edit the answer but I'm on mobile and i can't. I'll update it ASAP.

Comment: @faby, There's no real point. OP is generating invalid nested forms which is not supported and probably wont be consistent across different browsers anyway. This really needs to be solved a different ways (e.g. AJAX)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I know,  because of this I have suggested the OP a similar solution. Now I edit the answer to explain what to do and when I have more time i will add the code

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to MVC is to create a model in your GET method, use it in your View and POST the model in the Action that accept the Post verb. So, create a model class where you add all of your property (also the userid), in the view add at the top

```
@model YourClassModel
```

and your POST method

```
public ActionResult AddExpert(YourClassModel model)
```